# image div getting displaced while resizing the browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap page, Which is completely resposnive .

But for some reason, when I resize the browser, one of the div's images are getting displaced.

My code structure is like

```
<body>
  <div class="header-wrapper"> 
    -----
  </div>

  <div class="content-wrapper"> 
   ----
  </div>

  <div class="content-wrapper"> 
   ----
  </div>       
</body>
```

Is there anything standard which should've been there which I am missing regarding these displacements or it is something with my written code?

Please suggest

Comment: I suggest publishing a code snippet in a JSFiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Create a demo of the issue please.

Comment: Need more info about the issue

Comment: You code is plain, there is nothing going on magically. It is done by bootstrap itself. You can use the class col-xs-* to prevent the divs from stacking.

Comment: Try to add `.content-wrapper img {width:100%}`

Answer (score 0):

Add "img-responsive" class to the image tag

`<img src="..." class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">`

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive

Answer (score 0):

Some of the elements in bootstrap don't work out within your layout if you're not wrapping the entire html content inside of your body tag with a div.container or div.container-fluid.  It doesn't appear like you did that from your shared code.  See below:

```
<body>
 <div class="container">  <!--To wrap the doc, or conatiner-fluid for a wider container. -->
  <div class="header-wrapper"> 
  -----
  </div>
  <div class="content-wrapper"> 
  ----
  </div>
  <div class="content-wrapper"> 
  ----
  </div>
 </div>   <!--add @ end of doc -->
</body>
```

Above, would be my very first suggestion if you have not yet wrapped your document with a container.